# Ruby Vagrant network configuration duplication trouble, some objects references issue

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I will say right away - I'm experienced in Python for example, but Ruby is totally new for me so this question may be not related to Vagrant at all, I don't know, sorry.

I want to create two VMs on my host and created Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # Image config
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    config.disksize.size = '40GB'

    # Nodes specific configs
    config.vm.define "node_1_1" do |node|
        node.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.3.11", bridge: "enp4s0", netmask: "255.255.248.0"
        node.vm.hostname = "vm-ci-node-1-1"
    end

    config.vm.define "node_1_2" do |node|
        node.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.3.12", bridge: "enp4s0", netmask: "255.255.248.0"
        node.vm.hostname = "vm-ci-node-1-2"
    end

    # Nodes generic configs
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "2048"
        vb.cpus=2
    end
end
```

It works fine.

Then I decided to remove parameters hardcode and optimize it for next case with more than two VMs and for correct work on another machines with another bridge interface names. So I replaced `Nodes specific configs` section with:

```
    target_interface = nil
    for if_addr in Socket.getifaddrs
        if if_addr.addr.ipv4? and if_addr.addr.ip_address.include? '192.168'
            target_interface = if_addr.name
        end
    end

    hostindex = 8
    guestindices = [1, 2]
    # Nodes specific configs
    for guestindex in guestindices
        vm_code = 'node_' + hostindex.to_s() + '_' + guestindex.to_s()
        ip = '192.168.3.' + hostindex.to_s() + guestindex.to_s()
        hostname = 'vm-ci-node-' + hostindex.to_s() + '-' + guestindex.to_s()
        config.vm.define vm_code.dup do |node|
            node.vm.network "public_network", ip: ip.dup, bridge: target_interface, netmask: "255.255.248.0"
            node.vm.hostname = hostname.dup
        end
    end
```

Then I run `vagrant up` - no errors, but if I try to SSH to these two machines - I get strange behaviour:

1. `node_8_1` IP address is `192.168.3.82`, hostname - `vm-ci-node-8-2`
2. `node_8_2` IP address is `192.168.3.82`, hostname - `vm-ci-node-8-2`

As you see - it is same. Also there are another interface with same IP `10.0.2.15` - and it is trouble too, but it existed on previous version of config too.

I suspected that there are some Ruby references troubles so I used `dup` (I repeat, I'm totally new to Ruby, sorry). But it does not seem to work.

VM codes are different - `node_8_1` and `node_8_2`, but IP and hostnames are same.

Could anybody please point me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `for guestindex in guestindices` part is the cause of your trouble.

Try using `guestindices.each do |i|` or shorter `(1..2).each do |i|` instead.

Vagrant is mentioning this in their documentation for multi-machine provisioning, see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/tips.html#loop-over-vm-definitions:

> The for i in ... construct in Ruby actually modifies the value of i for each iteration, rather than making a copy. Therefore, when you run this, every node will actually provision with the same [value].